# How to disable moved table to next pages in LibreOfficeWriter?

Tags: libreoffice

I have a simple `.odt` file, which has only 2 pages. On the first page I have some short text and a table. This table is big, so it needs two pages.

[image]

When I open this file next time I see other contents, like this:
[image]

So In the first page I have only text, and my table was moved to the second and the third pages. What I have to do to block this move?

Comment: Please choose [**Table - Properties - Text Flow** tab](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.3/en-US/text/swriter/01/05090300.html) and check options there